# aggregate by conditioned to value in two columns

Tags: r, aggregate

dput of my sample data file here [actual data contains 40K records]

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("build", "client"), class = "factor"), 
V2 = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L), V3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("kwadmin", "kwbuildproject", 
"plugin.msvs"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("11/17/2013", 
"11/18/2013", "11/19/2013"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("INPRKUL1", 
"MUSTMAT1", "nzarvan", "semaols5", "USBVO-builduser"), class = "factor"), 
V6 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("fi-l-7001180", "in-l-kbxi012108", 
"nznpe-l-w700029", "sevst-l-0008645", "usbvo-w-0078540"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Here I want to use aggregate function to count the number of unique users by counting the unique user name fields and then to use each user name to search the file to get the dates where they have logged in and then count the number of feature and their names, which has been used by a particular user in a particular day.

Below is what is tried . I am not very sure if this at all correct as I am a newbie here in R. Any help would be appreciated.

```
dat<-read.csv("test.csv")
names(dat)<-c("Catagory","Feature_Version","Feature","Date","User_Name","Host_Name")
dat$Date[is.na(dat$Date)]<-0
dat$Date<-as.Date(dat$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
dat<-na.omit(dat)
#agg<-aggregate(cbind(Date)~User_Name,FUN=mean,by=list(unique(tolower(dat$User_Name))))
```

Please pardon me if this is silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what output you're looking for. Here is my interpretation of your question.

Count the unique user names:

```
nlevels(dat$User_Name)
# [1] 5
```

Count the unique features per user and per date:

```
aggregate(Feature ~ User_Name + Date, dat, function(x) length(unique(x)))
#         User_Name       Date Feature
# 1         nzarvan 2013-11-17       1
# 2 USBVO-builduser 2013-11-17       2
# 3         nzarvan 2013-11-18       1
# 4        INPRKUL1 2013-11-19       1
# 5        MUSTMAT1 2013-11-19       1
# 6        semaols5 2013-11-19       1
```

Comment: thanks .. your statement showed me the direction which I wanted in my program. thanks again caio